Why do two transformer efficiency formulas yield different results?
I've encountered two different methods for calculating the efficiency of a transformer, and they yield different results. I'm trying to understand why this happens and which method is more appropriate in different scenarios.
Method 1: Efficiency based on power losses:
$$\text{Efficiency} = 1 - \frac{P_{\text{loss}}}{P_{\text{in}}}$$
Method 2: Efficiency based on real parts of apparent power:
$$\text{Efficiency} = \frac{\Re\{S_{\text{out}}\}}{\Re\{S_{\text{in}}\}}$$
I'd expect these two methods to provide the same result, given that the real part of the apparent power is the actual usable power, however, that isn't the case. I've observed that the efficiency ratio based on the real parts of the apparent power is always less than the power losses-based efficiency. Doesn't that imply that there is power loss in the inductors (I know that's not possible but still why)? Can someone explain why these discrepancies occur and why one of the methods would be more appropriate?

I figure you probably mean to say complex power instead of apparent power? Aside from that, can you provide an example of your calculations?

I have used both formulas and always got the same results (unless I was doing some mistake). You can follow the deduction if you have some doubt. Starting from your first formula:
$$\eta=1-\frac{P_{loss}}{P_{in}}$$
where \$\eta\$ is the efficiency, \$P_{loss}\$ are the losses of the equipment and \$P_{in}\$ is the input power of your equipment.
To find the equivalence, we will need the relation \$P_{in}=P_{out}+P_{loss}\$, which means that the power entering your equipment is being delivered by your equipment or is being lost in your equipment. We can also write it as \$P_{loss}=P_{in}-P_{out}\$.
Then, replacing \$P_{loss}\$ by \$P_{in}-P_{out}\$ in the first equation we get:
$$\eta=1-\frac{P_{in}-P_{out}}{P_{in}}$$
which can be written as:
$$\eta=1-\frac{P_{in}}{P_{in}}+\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}$$
the next step will be:
$$\eta=1-1+\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}$$
and finally:
$$\eta=\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}$$
which is your second formula.
So, trusting in Math, we can say that both formula will give you the same result.
